# SVG background-image not rotating at center

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm displaying spinner via `background-image` property.

As you can see in the example, spinner is not rotating from it's center.

I tried with `transform-origin` property but it's not working.

```css
body {
  background: #5daf47;
}
.spinner {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3057457/spinner.svg');
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Here is a content of my svg:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    svg {
      width: 150px;
      animation: loading 3s linear infinite;
    }

    circle {
      animation: loading-circle 2s linear infinite;
      stroke: white;
      fill: transparent;
      -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
      -moz-transform-origin: center center;
      -ms-transform-origin: center center;
      -o-transform-origin: center center;
      transform-origin: center center;
    }

    @keyframes loading {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes loading-circle {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -600;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="60" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="300" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
</svg>
```

How can I make this spinner to rotate from center?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using Firefox? But it works in Chrome/IE?

Comment: @Robbie I only test it in Chrome. Didn't try Firefox/IE.

Comment: Ok - reason for asking is that there's a Firefox bug where, even with transform origin set, if it's not directly on the parent, Firefox will rotate around 0,0 and not the origin. But as it's not Firefox, saved me looking...

Comment: I think you may need to rethink it. It shows a green box in firefox, so 50% of your viewers will not be able to see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out. The problem was that I didn't set `transform-origin` style to `<svg>` tag like so:

```
<svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    svg {
      width: 150px;
      animation: loading 3s linear infinite;
      /* INSERTED CODE BELOW IS THE SOLUTION */
      -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
      -moz-transform-origin: center center;
      -ms-transform-origin: center center;
      -o-transform-origin: center center;
      transform-origin: center center;
    }

    circle {
      animation: loading-circle 2s linear infinite;
      stroke: white;
      fill: transparent;
      -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
      -moz-transform-origin: center center;
      -ms-transform-origin: center center;
      -o-transform-origin: center center;
      transform-origin: center center;
    }

    @keyframes loading {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes loading-circle {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -600;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="60" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="300" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round"></circle>
</svg>
```

Final solution:

```css
html,body {
  background: #5daf47;
}
.spinner {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  background-size: 150px;
  background-image: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3057457/spinner2.svg');
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner"></div>
```

Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: For future reference: This SVG spinner works well in Chrome/FF. It does not work well in IE. Instead, GIF spinner should be used for modern browsers for a max compatibility.

Comment: It doesn't even show in Firefox. Also if you are adding the class to a div you are spinning the div, not the svg background, surely